# File content not persistent when we call msync from different context

Tags: c, linux, memory

I have two context namely process1 and process2 sharing same mapped area, process1 syncs data to the file most of the times,whereas process2 does sync only once before system goes for reboot to make sure all the datas are synced.**I find the data to be intact in the file before the system goes for reboot and once the system comes up after reboot i find the data that are synced by process2 alone to be missing**.

**Note:**

1. mmap flag:  map_shared for both the processes.
2. msync flag: ms_sync for both the processes.
3. There are no flock issues b/w processes.
4. Error codes are checked for all processes.

**Sorry i cannot share the complete code,but i have pasted minimal part of it i think this should do.**

```
**/*Process1(Daemon process)
* This process does syncing on two files int_fd and ext_fd. It stacks upto 50 messages and * then does a sync for every 50 messages.If the system goes for reboot within these 50     * messages then process2 does syncing before going for reboot. 
*/**
    int_cntr -> file1 data counter(when int_cntr==50 does syncing for file1) 
    ext_cntr -> file2 data counter(when ext_cntr==50 does syncing for file2)
    my_flg -> this flag will be set only when any counter reaches 50.
    int_fd-> file1 to be synced
    ext_fd-> file2 to be synced

    **/*This is a daemon process so mapping is done only once during booting of this    process it is done exactly as shown in process2*/**

**/*Counter value check*/**
      **/*checks counter values int_cntr and ext_cntr and sets flag "**my_flg**"only when any of the counter reaches 50,.*/** 

**/*Syncing part*/**
-> checks the **my_flg** if it is set,then files will be locked.
-> Uses locks/Unlocks with same flags mentioned in process2.
-> Call msync with MS_SYNC,exact flags are used as shown in process2
-> reset the corresponding counter
-> if the my_flg is not set then data will be added to the queue syncing will not be done.



**/*Process2
* This process will be called when system goes for reboot,before going for reboot it syncs * the data to corresponding files.
*/**
    int_fd-> file1 to be synced
    ext_fd-> file2 to be synced

            ha_int_file = mmap(0, sizeof (file1), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                                MAP_SHARED, int_fd, 0);
            ha_ext_file = mmap(0, sizeof (file2), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                                MAP_SHARED, ext_fd, 0);

            if(ha_int_file== MAP_FAILED || ha_ext_file==MAP_FAILED)
                printf("Process2 mmap failed,errno =%d\n",errno);
            /*
             * Take the LOCK for syncing file1
             */
            if ((flock_rc = flock(int_fd, LOCK_EX)) != 0) {
                printf("Forcesync Internal file lock failed##############\n");
                rc = ERROR;
            } else {
                if(msync(ha_int_file, sizeof (rls_storage_file_t), MS_SYNC | MS_INVALIDATE)) {
                    printf("Forcesync Internal file sync failed,errno =%d##############\n",errno);
                    rc = ERROR;
                } else
                    printf("Force sync successful for internal file#####################\n");
            /*
             * Release the lock on file1
             */    
                if ((flock_rc = flock(int_fd, LOCK_UN)) != 0) {
                    printf("Forcesync Internal file un-lock failed##############\n");
                    rc = ERROR;
                }

            }

            /*
             * Take the LOCK for syncing file2
             */
            if ((flock_rc = flock(ext_fd, LOCK_EX)) != 0) {
                printf("Forcesync External file lock failed##############\n");
                rc = ERROR;
            } else {
                if(msync(ha_ext_file, sizeof (rls_storage_file_t), MS_SYNC | MS_INVALIDATE)) {
                    printf("Forcesync External file sync failed=%d##############\n",errno);
                    rc = ERROR;
                } else
                    printf("Force sync successful for external file#####################\n");
            /*
             * Release the LOCK on file2
             */    
                if ((flock_rc = flock(ext_fd, LOCK_UN)) != 0) {
                    printf("Forcesync External file un-lock failed##############\n");
                    rc= ERROR;
                }
            }

            close(int_fd);
            close(ext_fd);
```

**Summary of Issue:**

Lets say that i have received 255 messages,for every 50 messages sync will be done by process1,so 250 messages are synced by process1 now the rest of the messages(5 messages) will be added to the queue by process1. Suppose if the system goes for reboot now Process2 will do syncing of these 5 messages to the corresponding file. After synced by process2 i take a copy of the file before system goes for reboot.I find the data to be intact in the copy i took before reboot,and after system comes up i find the data synced by process2 alone to be missing. As per our example the last 5 messages synced by process 2 alone is missing.

**Note:**
**I do not see the issue when i sync from same process i.e process1 before going for reboot,i see it only when i sync from process2 before going for reboot.**

can someone brief me this **MS_INVALIDATE** flag,is there anything it can do in this case.

Comment: Even if you can't share the original code, you can at least try to create a minimal example that exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: Hi Drew,I have added part of the code and explanations here and there to give it some shape,please help me in further debugging the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer just a few thoughts. Typically if you are sharing memory you would be sharing memory first and then mapping said memory to a file.

It is fine to share memory between processes so long as you acquired that shared memory through some sort of legitimate shared memory mechanism (like shmat/shmget). Even though you would be using shared memory you would likely want to interact with that memory using threading primitives which provide for memory barriers/checkpoints.

If you can't use threading primitives you can manually create memory barriers in your code using gcc primitives like __sync_synchronize(). Likely similar for Visual Studio and other compilers.

Once you are confident that the memory is consistent between the two processes, whichever one wants to do the final synchronize step should call msync, munmap, and then exit.

Comment: Hi Claris, what do you mean by memory is consistent,i took a copy of the file before system goes for reboot i find my data there then its consistent only right?. But after reboot i do not find the last part of data alone that was synced.

Comment: Moreover I'm a beginner can u explain a little what is this memory barrier.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your first statement. Files don't get un-written once written.

Comment: re: memory barrier, wikipedia it.

Comment: I forgot to mention one more thing i do not see the issue if i do syncing from process1 before going for reboot. I see it only when i sync from process2.